# How to specify a List<MyCustomType> as a "Return Type" for a UML Interface Property

Tags: visio, generic-list, user-defined-types

In my Visio 2007 UML document I am unable to figure out how I can add an operation to an Interface that returns a generic `List<MyCustomType>` type.

For example:

Say I have a class named "MyClass" and an Interface named "IFace". IFace has a signature of a method that returns a Generic List of MyClass.

For clarity, here's an example of the C# code:

```
namespace StackO
{
    public interface IFace
    {
        List<MyClass> SomeMethod(string data);    
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of where I'm stuck:
[image]

It seems as though the only way to specify a `List<MyClass>` as my Return Type is to create another user-defined datatype that is explicitly written as `List<MyClass>`. If this is the case, so be it. However, I'm posting this in hopes that there is a better/proper way to do this.

How can I define the Return Type of an Operation of a Visio Interface to be a Generic List of a User-Defined Datatype?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Class diagram properties > Go to operations >  select the return type you are interested in changing and click properties.

In the next dialog you will have option for setting prefix `List<` and suffix `>`.

This way you can specify the return type as `List<>`.

I see this option in Visio 2010. But I am not sure if this option is available in Visio 2007.

Comment: Thanks, kumar. FYI - Visio 2007 does support the prefix/suffix Return Type Expressions.

Answer (score 14):

**There is no such a thing as `T1<T2>` in UML class diagrams**.

If you want to specify that the method returns several values, the correct notation is:

```
SomeMethod(data: String) : MyClass [*]
```

This notation is much more powerful than the one used by C#. `List<MyClass> SomeMethod(string data)` gives no information about the contract of the method. With UML, you know that in:

```
SomeMethod(data: String) : MyClass [*]
SomethingElse() : String [1..*]
LastExample(number: UnlimitedNatural) : Integer [0..1]
```

`SomeMethod` returns a sequence containing zero or more elements. `SomethingElse` returns a sequence of one or several elements: this sequence is never empty. Finally, `LastExample` returns an optional value. This could be expressed in C# as `int? LastExample(uint number)` — see, no `IEnumerable` here.

Also note that:

```
SomeMethod(data: String) : MyClass [0..*]
```

shouldn't be used, since `[*]` means the same thing and is shorter. As for:

```
SomeMethod(data: String) : MyClass [0..n]
```

is incorrect, despite being used a lot on the internet.

Comment: Though your answer is correct from an academic point of view, the intended semantics of using `List<MyCustomType>` for a return type is pretty clear, so why not allow a pragmatic solution? Only because Viso does not support it? (The accepted answer is indeed an extremly ugly hack and I would avoid it, of course).

Comment: @DocBrown: I believe it's clear for a Java or C# programmer. Other languages may use other syntax for generics, and use `A<B>` for something other than generics. It seems awkward to me to use a construct proper to a specific language in UML, which should be language-agnostic.

Comment: As soon as one uses data types in UML, it becomes language dependend to some degree, so what you write is also true for types like "int". And using UML in an language-agnostic way is not everyones requirement.

Comment: @DocBrown: it's an interesting remark. Personally, I always conceived UML as a way to describe a solution to a problem in a perfectly language-agnostic way, and only then implement the solution in a specific language, using its power and circumventing its limitations. In that way, for me, UML is the thing one keeps when migrating the app from a language to another.

Comment: That is *one* possible use case for UML class diagrams - but to my experience, people use UML much more often in a context where the programming languages are well-known and fixed (that's maybe because a programming language is an architectural decision that is always really hard to change at a later point in time, with or without UML class diagrams).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but, if you are modeling an existing system, not to migrate it to another language, but for whatever other reason (understanding it for example?) it is rather useful to be able to distinguish between the actual implementation. Whether the person used List<T> or T[] or IEnumerable<T>, etc, can make a big difference.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was looking for the proper way to document an operation that returns a collection without being too language-specific.

Comment: An additional note: in Visio 2007, you can only specify attribute multiplicity. You cannot define the return type of an operation to have multiplicity.